# Can I use an extension method to add a column AND a foreign key constraint with Fluent Migrator?

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

**I have an extension method that is used by several tables:**

```
public static ICreateTableColumnOptionOrWithColumnSyntax WithUser(this ICreateTableWithColumnSyntax tableWithColumnSyntax)
{
    return tableWithColumnSyntax
        .WithColumn("UserId")
            .AsInt32()
            .Nullable();
}
```

**Here is an example table using it:**

```
Create.Table("UserSettings")
    .WithUser()
    .WithColumn("SomeValue")
        .AsString(1)
        .Nullable();
```

**I then have to add a foreign key manually every time like so:**

```
Create.ForeignKey()
    .FromTable("UserSettings")
       .ForeignColumn("UserID")
   .ToTable("Users")
       .PrimaryColumn("Id");
```

Is there a way to package the foreign key declaration in the extension method `WithUser()` so that I *(and more importantly, other people on my team)* don't have to specify it every time?

Comment: Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This ended up being easier than expected. Here is the code to do this:**

```
public static ICreateTableColumnOptionOrWithColumnSyntax WithUser(this ICreateTableWithColumnSyntax tableWithColumnSyntax)
{
    return tableWithColumnSyntax
        .WithColumn("UserId")
            .AsInt32()
            .Nullable()
            .ForeignKey("Users", "Id");
}
```

I just wish this was better documented somewhere.

Comment: Feel free to add this to the FluentMigrator wiki. It's open to everyone.

Comment: Just what I need, 7 years later, thanks Jared